# Moving identity authentication to services layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to move asp.net identity 3 authentication from controller to service, n tier architecture, that will manage user authentication.At first I would like to know if it's good idea to move authentication from controller to service layer.
Everything goes fine ,until I try to use UserManager.CreateAsync() method, method stops working and is redirecting to same register page. 
Here`s my Account Service code:

```
namespace CVProject.Services.Account
{
    public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _DbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<UserRole> _roleManager;

        public AccountService(ApplicationDbContext DbContext,
            UserManager<User> userManager,
            SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            RoleManager<UserRole> roleManager)
        {
            _DbContext = DbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }


        public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateEmployeeAccount(EmployeeRegisterViewModel model)
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email, Name = (model.FirstName + model.LastName)};
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if(result.Succeeded)
            {
                if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(model.Role))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new UserRole(model.Role));
                }
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,model.Role);
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

And my controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(EmployeeRegisterViewModel employeeRegisterModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _service.CreateEmployeeAccount(employeeRegisterModel);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(EmployeeController.Index), "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(employeeRegisterModel);
    }
```

And startup.cs code ,that could affect this code:

```
 services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DbContextConnection"]));


        services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>(config => 
            {
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Employee/Login";
            })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext,string>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the `CreateEmployeeAccount`?

Comment: No, But I guess it was problem with SignInManager and RoleManager ,cause when I deleted them it worked fine.

Comment: Ok glad you figured it out. Good going.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sign in an user while being logged with the one doing the request. You may have some issues there.

Remove this code `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);`